Why does ffmpeg/ffprobe report the wrong SAR?
The SAR reported by ffprobe for the same file differs from the Pixel Aspect value in QuickTime Player. If I understand correctly, SAR and PAR mean the same thing. Since the file is in NTSC DVD format, why does QuickTime Player report the correct value but ffprobe reports the wrong value? (Actually the DARs of VLC and QuickTime Player are also different according to these values)
Input #0, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_1.mpeg':
  Duration: 00:22:00.07, start: 0.280633, bitrate: 20558 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9396000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:3[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:4[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle (dvdsub)



Afaik, SAR and PAR can be different. Anyway, what value do you find ffprobe shows incorrectly ? I dont see it.

720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3] I think SAR should be 10:11 for NTSC DVD format.

DVDs are typically meant for 4:3 display, so ffmpeg is notionally correct. However, DVD standard has legacy support for DVDs authored from sources like analog TV or D1, where 704 of 720 were active pixels, and 8 pixels on either side are meant to be cropped out. ffmpeg does take that into account by reading the Sequence Display Extension. Maybe QT doesn't.

@Gyan As you can see from Wikipedia, the NTSC standard only defines 10:11 or 40:33. That is why I am pointing out that ffprobe is wrong. In fact, the black bars are given to the left and right of the video data, so if what you are saying is correct, the black bars should be cropped when played back in VLC, but they remain and the entire video is displayed in 4:3. In other words, the width is reduced by the black bars, producing an incorrect aspect ratio.

The NTSC standard is not relevant here. MPEG-2 is, which only signals DAR. If the frame is to be cropped, the file must signal it in the Sequence Display Extension, which ffmpeg does parse.

@Gyan I do not know how to verify the Sequence Display Extension. Is there a way to check the Sequence Display Extension?

Run ffmpeg -debug pict -i INPUT and check the logs for a line containing sde

@Gyan I could not find the string “sde”. This means that ffmpeg only refers to the DAR to determine the pixel ratio, while QuickTime Player refers to other information to determine the pixel ratio, right?

No, it means the input does not have SDE and hence QT should consider the full width for the pixel ratio, but it seems not to.

Where then is 10:11 derived from? We all know that the correct pixel ratio for NTSC DVD is 10:11. This file is the raw DVD file itself.
